# Where can a list of Desktop web browsers be found at?

Tags: browsers

I have another question posted in regards to the practicality of whitelisting.  In this question I'm simply looking for an frequently updated list of top known used Desktop web browsers to use as part of my whitelist.

I'm not trying to target any specific OS so please show one, show all.  The list of browsers for desktops isn't exploding, but it does grow.  I've only recently been made aware of other browsers that have multiple rendering engines.  I'm not always on top of the text based browsers found out there either.

I'm aware of the mobile browser platform and there is an active list used with regular expression for identification purposes that I will use as well as whatever I can find for the desktop platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of web browsers here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers